# Angular 6 page redirection issue while using angular datatables

Tags: angular, datatables, angular-datatables

I'm using [angular-datatables](https://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/#/getting-started) in my angular 6 application. If I try to go to that page it will gets redirects again to homepage. In case If I hide the table it will goes to that page. And also I didn't get any error in the console. I don't know from where the route gets redirected. 
Someone please help me to solve the problem.

**Stackblitz url**

[Issue](https://angular-datatable-redirect.stackblitz.io/)

[Editor url](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-datatable-redirect)

Answer (score 0):

I wrongly put the authorisation check so only page gets redirected to the homepage.